# Is using Regex better than string split

Tags: c#, regex

I receive a string response from a certain component which looks:

```
"RX,993-756-V01 ver 02a ,4A7DF39B,124-412,0,0,0,1,8002,S, ,993-760-V01 ver 01b"
```

and use a simple string separator to split the response to a string[] and enumerate to retrieve the contents.

```
char[] separator = { ',', '\r' };
string[] data = rxBuffer.Split(separator);  //rxBuffer has the string response
```

Now the data object shall contain:

```
data[0] = RX
data[1] = 993-756-V01 ver 02a 
data[2] = 4A7DF39B.. so on
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way than this ( for ex: using **Regex** ) where I can query the entire response and parse each entries into separate variables.

```
i.e., data[1] into a variable called SWVersion property etc.
```

Comment: Regex is never *more efficient* than a simple split.

Comment: Destructuring in C# is not yet available. However, you could get a dictionary with regex match results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, I'm aware of that but wanted to know if at all it is really efficient in cases like above

Comment: Then the answer is clear: sting split will be more efficient. In this case, where your input string is formatted perfectly, string split approach is just the most appropriate. Regex is only necessary when your string is not formatted well, contains rubbish you need to "exclude"/remove, or when you do not know exact separators (but there is a common pattern that fits them all).

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are a heavyweight solution to string analysis problem. It is based on a state machine that is built from the raw expression. It gets somewhat better if you can compile regular expression once and then use it multiple times in a row, which depends on the problem you are solving.

On the other hand, string splitting is almost trivial from implementation point of view. It boils down to recognizing the separator at each position of input and deciding whether to start a new output element or to push current position to the last output element. That executes faster than regular expressions.

From functional point of view, string splitting is also better because you can apply LINQ library to chain entire data processing into one statement:

```
rxBuffer.Split(separator)
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => !s.IsNullOrEmpty())
    .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, 3))
    ...
```

This is just an example of a possible analysis which filters out empty strings and groups the remaining ones by the first three letters. You don't get such simplicity with regular expressions, nor do you get the speed.